# Finding Duplicates & Putting them in Master Folder

Tags: excel, vba

My code renames folders based on what is in first column:

```
Dim sFolder As String

Option Explicit
Sub addPrefix()
Dim strfile As String
Dim filenum As String

Dim strOldDirName
Dim strNewDirName

strfile = Dir(sFolder)
Dim old_name, new_name As String




    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   strOldDirName = sFolder & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 2).Value
strNewDirName = sFolder & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 2).Value
Name strOldDirName As strNewDirName

        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

and then I check for duplicates on Column C (email column). If they are a duplicate I move them to their 'master' folder (which is just the first of the duplicates found). Upon this, it adds the suffix ' - MASTER' on to the folder.

Here is the code to move duplicates:

```
    Sub moveDuplicates()
' This will find duplicates and move them into a master folder. It'll will then delete the row

Dim masterID
Dim masterPlatform
Dim objFileSystem

Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String


Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Dim masterOldFolderName
Dim masterNewFolderName


Dim masterSuffix


Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim rngWhole As Range, rngSplit As Range


masterID = 0
masterPlatform = 0

masterSuffix = " - MASTER"

masterOldFolderName = ""
masterNewFolderName = ""

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")

LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Set rngWhole = .Range("C1:C" & LastRow)
.Range("E" & 1).Value = rngWhole
For i = 1 To LastRow

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngWhole, .Range("C" & i).Value) > 1 Then

Set rngSplit = .Range("C1:C" & i)

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngSplit, .Range("C" & i).Value) = 1 Then

    masterID = .Range("B" & i).Value
    masterPlatform = .Range("A" & i).Value


            '' Renme master folders with subfix of "- MASTER"
            masterOldFolderName = sFolder & masterPlatform & " " & masterID
            masterNewFolderName = sFolder & masterPlatform & " " & masterID & masterSuffix
            Name masterOldFolderName As masterNewFolderName
            '' End of renaming


'.Range("D" & i).Value = "MASTER " & masterID

Else
'.Range("D" & i).Value = "CHILD " & masterID & " This folder: " & .Range("B" & i).Value



'MOVING FOLDER
    FromPath = sFolder & .Range("A" & i).Value & " " & .Range("B" & i).Value '<< Change
    ToPath = sFolder & masterPlatform & " " & masterID & masterSuffix & "\"  '<< needs the slash to go into the folder

    .Range("H" & i).Value = "From: " & FromPath
    .Range("I" & i).Value = "From: " & ToPath


    'Check if source and target folder exists
    If objFileSystem.FolderExists(FromPath) = True And objFileSystem.FolderExists(ToPath) = True Then
        objFileSystem.MoveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
        lblStatus.Caption = "Moving " & FromPath & " To " & ToPath




        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        lblStatus.Caption = " Deleting " & .Range("A" & i).Value & " " & .Range("B" & i).Value
        'MsgBox "Source folder has moved to target folder"
    Else
        'MsgBox "Either source or target folder does not exist"
    End If

    ' END OF MOVING FOLDER

' ROW GETS DELETED


End If

'.Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3


End If

Next i

End With


End Sub
```

My script works to a certain degree:

[image]

But it just puts everything into the first 'MASTER' folder

[image]

Here is my sheet:

[image]

I then call this from a button:

```
    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End If
    End With

    If sFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
        Me.txtFolderPath.Text = sFolder

        '' calls functions
        addPrefix
        moveDuplicates
        Sheet_SaveAs ' saves output
end sub
```

Is the reason it is not performing as expected due to I am calling it wrongly?

Full code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k06b5hydc4v7bpn/so-files.zip?dl=0

(code can be run from developer> forms> userform1)

**DEBUGGING**:

I think the problem seems to arise here when debugging:

```
    '' Renme master folders with subfix of "- MASTER"
    masterOldFolderName = sFolder & masterPlatform & " " & masterID
    masterNewFolderName = sFolder & masterPlatform & " " & masterID & masterSuffix
    Name masterOldFolderName As masterNewFolderName
    '' End of renaming
```

I am not sure if this is because it is in the wrong place (which I assume)

Comment: A few things... `Dim sFolder as String` is declared outside of the `Sub addPrefix()` so when you run the code it will be implied as `Variant` by default. `sFolder` is also not assigned any value so it's an empty string or `""`.

Comment: Is there an error? If so which and where? • Also what is wrong with the code? What does *"not performing as expected"* exactly mean? What is different from what you expected.

Comment: No error, which makes me believe its a logic error. I have also uploaded my fiull code

Comment: @SamuelEverson If you `Dim sFolder as String` outside a sub it means it is a global variable that is defined as `String` for all subs. So there is nothing implied as `Variant` by default here (beseides `old_name` which has no type specified and there fore is `Variant`. It should be `Dim old_name As String, new_name As String`).

Comment: @BCLtd Did you debug your code? Go through it step by step using F8. In every step check the value of your variables and see if it is what you expect. This way you will find a logic issue. See [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Oh I think I've misunderstood something with global declarations, I'd thought `Dim` could only declare within a procedure and for a `Global` it would be something like `Global sFolder As String`. My mistake.

Comment: @SamuelEverson for your interest `Dim` at modul level is the same as `Private`. See [Declaring variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables#private-statement)

Comment: Hi, I have just included to where I believe the issue lies whilst debugging (maybe in the wrong place logically). Apologies, rather a newbie at this :)

Comment: @BCLtd What is the value of `masterOldFolderName`, `masterNewFolderName` and `sFolder`?

Comment: sfolder is the folder selected from the button (a dialog box appears and you select the folder). masteroldfoldername is the sfolder path/ coumn a & column b... the newfolder name just adds ' - master' at the end

Comment: p.s. i uploaded the code

Comment: Well maybe you misunderstood, I wanted to know the **exact** values not an explanation. That is what I meant with debug and check your variable values.

Comment: Sorry!

it is writing the same master stuff in the loop, e.g. the first one in the the list

newfoldername: C:\Users\John\Documents\Work\Files\Dropbox 8384 - MASTER
old: to: C:\Users\John\Documents\Work\Files\Dropbox 8384

Comment: It's like if i were to do a loop, the values need to be cleared before the loop starts next increment (if that makes sense)